# how to create jar for specific packages maven

Tags: java, maven, jar

I am working on a maven project. I want to create jar for the specific packages
This is the project structure, I want to create jar containing only **dca** and **common** how do i achieve this.

```
myproject
|
--src
   |
   --main
        |
        --java
           |
           --common
           --dca
           --model
       --resources
   --test
--pom.xml
```

Can i achive this using **maven-jar-plugin**

Comment: Why do you have this requirement? It looks like you're trying to solve a problem that is on a different place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could seperate your project into submodules, where you have two submodules:

- common
- dca

These submodules would be seperate Maven artifacts in the same `groupId` as you currently have. Any module containing submodules must be packaged as `pom`, and hence cannot contain source code itself.

Code that depends on either package (for example, some kind of user interface, or web components) would reside in another submodule, say `web` or `gui`, and that submodule would have a Maven dependency on the `common` or `dca` artifact.

Summarising, your structure would look like this:

- root --> packaging `pom`

  - web --> packaging `war`
  - gui --> packaging `jar`
  - other --> packaging `pom`

    - dca --> packaging `jar`
    - common --> packaging `jar`

Comment: There might be other ways to achieve it, this is just how I would solve it. I think it would be the best way to achieve the desired result (assuming the requirement is just as you described it).

Comment: this mYproject is already a submodule..can i create another submodule?

Comment: Yes, modules can have submodules, and submodules can have submodules themselve. As far as I know, the only limitation is Windows not supporting file paths longer than 255 characters.

Comment: my project have a packaging jar.so when i create a submodule its giving error The parent project must have a packaging type of POM,

Answer (score 3):

maven-jar-plugin can be customized to include / exclude specific file. You can achieve this by configuring in pom.xml like below.

```
<plugin>
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
.
.
<configuration>
    <excludes>
        <exclude>**/model/*</exclude>
    </excludes>
</configuration> 
.
.
</plugin>
```